# Is there a way to set the <div> width to 100% of the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a pure HTML /CSS webpage. I made a dropdown menu, but I cannot set it to full width.

Here is a codepen of it.

https://codepen.io/SynergyOfLife/pen/ExyZdZz

I am using Bootstrap 4.5.2.

My `.header` div does not fill 100% of the width no matter what I try. I want it to fill 100%, with the example text under it.

Help would be appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the background color to the header instead of the li. Then remove float from the li and replace it with display inline-block. You can also use display flex on the ul.

Comment: Good answer - I had to figure it out instead of somebody pasting the code; I learned something. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The **Reason** why you were unable to get it resolved was because you were setting `float:left` for the `<ui>` element - which forces your ui container to the left restricting it to occupy the full width of the page.

**Solved**

I have corrected the CSS the way you desire

**Proposed CSS**

```
.header{
  width:100%;
}
.header .main-navigation ul:nth-child(1){
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  justify-content:center;
  background-color: red;
}
.header .main-navigation ul li {
  padding: 20px 0;
  background-color: red;
}
.header .main-navigation ul li a {
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.header .main-navigation ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.header .main-navigation ul li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0, -10px);
}

.header .main-navigation ul li ul li {
  clear: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 180px;
}
```

**Result**
[image]

**Also** if you want the `<li>` elements i.e. the menu options to appear to the left then you can just change the `justify-content` to `flex-start` instead of `center`.

Do tell me wether you desired the same or not :)

Comment: Good answer! I like the thought process in finding the solution, you taught me something.

Comment: Thats  what I wanted :) and yeah I recommend you learning about ``display:flex`` its super awesome.Once you get it you'll be all done with structuring and positioning your div in the right places with the right styles. And if you liked the answer above pls give it an *upvote*.Thank you !

Comment: I only have 5 reputation and I need 15 to upvote. I will upvote as soon as I get 15 reputation though!

Comment: Oh my mistake I didn't see ! Not a problem Ok then I'll upvote your question to get you to 15 ;)

Comment: I wish there were more users like you. Thanks!